# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'iosSlider'

Tags: jquery

Looking to you experts for some help...
Our Site is using iosSlider (https://iosscripts.com/iosslider/) for a mobile slider... however, in Chrome Inspector I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'iosSlider'
```

I've checked, and jQuery is only loaded once in the head before calling the iosSlider js... which is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* some custom settings */
    $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
        desktopClickDrag: true,
        snapToChildren: true,
        infiniteSlider: true,
        navSlideSelector: '.sliderContainer .slideSelectors .item',
        scrollbar: true,
        scrollbarContainer: '.sliderContainer .scrollbarContainer',
        scrollbarMargin: '0',
        scrollbarBorderRadius: '0',
        keyboardControls: true
    });

});
```

also tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* some custom settings */
   jQuery('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
        desktopClickDrag: true,
        snapToChildren: true,
        infiniteSlider: true,
        navSlideSelector: '.sliderContainer .slideSelectors .item',
        scrollbar: true,
        scrollbarContainer: '.sliderContainer .scrollbarContainer',
        scrollbarMargin: '0',
        scrollbarBorderRadius: '0',
        keyboardControls: true
    });

});
```

to no avail though.. any help?

---

**UPDATE**:  This is how we're calling the library:

```
 <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
        <script src="//twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.iosslider.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/corecalls.js"></script>
```

the iosslider function is called within corecall.js

Comment: Have you actually included `isoSlider.js`?

Comment: Did you include the `iosSlider` library?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the `isoSlider.js` script is loaded after `jquery.js`? This sure looks like a script order issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the iosSlider plugin is not included. It should be included afer jQuery and before the   `jQuery('.iosSlider').iosSlider({` call

Comment: Updated the original question which shows how we're calling the iosSlider librar

Comment: I think you have an extra slash in `/js/jquery.iosslider.min.js` at the beginning. Shouldn't it be `js/jquery.iosslider.min.js` ? There is an easy way to verify if a library is well loaded. Open your page in Google Chrome, press ctrl+u to see the source code, and then click on the link `/js/jquery.iosslider.min.js`, if it shows you the iosslider source code, it means that everything is correct, but if it's a 404 not found, it means that the path to your js file is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Its an order of loading issue.  you need to load JQuery first then the iosSlider.js for the slider.  I'll be adding this to http://www.WebsiteDesignAndSupport.com

So matthew.perron  answer is correct.